# one single scroll bar for two QTextEdit, pyqt4, python

Tags: python-3.x, scrollbar, pyqt4, qtextedit

How to make one single scroll bar for two QTextEdit, pyqt4, python. Or how to synchronize two scrollbars of two QTextEdit. For simultaneous scrolling texts.
Pyqt4, python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-connect the [value changed signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#value-prop) of all the scrollbars:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.edit1 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.edit2 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit1)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit2)
        self.edit1.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.edit2.horizontalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.edit1.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.edit2.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.edit2.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.edit1.horizontalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.edit2.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.edit1.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
        text = '\n'.join(name for name in dir(QtCore))
        self.edit1.setText(text)
        self.edit2.setText(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 600, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for  your help!